# Counter of iterations in comprehension list with nested loops

Tags: python, matrix

```
X =[
    [2, 10, 3, 1],
    [4, 2, 0, 7],
    [6, 9, 6, 9],
    [1, 3, 4, 5]
]

Y =[
    [4, 2, 3, 1],
    [9, 9, 9, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
]
```

So i have to add these two matrixes. I solved it, but i have to create counter of iterations.

```
def summary(X, Y):
    return [X[i][j] + Y[i][j] for j in range(len(X[0]))] for i in range(len(X))]
```

I was searching for the solution and also trying to figure it out by myself, but i have no idea what to do if there is already two loops inside this list.

```
Desired output:

[6, 12, 6, 2]
[13, 11, 9, 14]
[7, 11, 9, 13]
[6, 9, 11, 13]

number of iterations: 16
```

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
np.reshape(np.array(X) + np.array(Y), (4,4)).tolist()
# output
# [[6, 12, 6, 2], [13, 11, 9, 14], [7, 11, 9, 13], [6, 9, 11, 13]]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension to do element-wise addition

```
>>> [[i+j for i,j in zip(a, b)] for a,b in zip(X,Y)]
[[6, 12, 6, 2],
 [13, 11, 9, 14],
 [7, 11, 9, 13],
 [6, 9, 11, 13]]
```

In general (unless this is a learning exercise) I'd suggest using `numpy` as it is significantly faster for linear algebra operations

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(X) + np.array(Y)
array([[ 6, 12,  6,  2],
       [13, 11,  9, 14],
       [ 7, 11,  9, 13],
       [ 6,  9, 11, 13]])
```

If you wanted to do this "by hand" while keeping a counter you could do something like

```
def add(X,Y):
    ops = 0
    result = []
    for a, b in zip(X,Y):
        row = []
        for i,j in zip(a, b):
            row.append(i + j)
            ops += 1
        result.append(row)
    print('number of iterations: {}'.format(ops))
    return result

>>> add(X, Y)
number of iterations: 16
[[6, 12, 6, 2], [13, 11, 9, 14], [7, 11, 9, 13], [6, 9, 11, 13]]
```

Comment: well, okay, but have to get amount of operations in that nested list comprehension, that's the question

Comment: The number of operations is just the number of elements in your array (16 in this case)

Comment: I have one more question, i have to make multiplication of matrixes, i also solve it, but there is something like switching rows with columns, whether this will affect the number of operations?

ps. is that possible to make solution with this counter inside, or in this case (nested comprehension list) it's impossible?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is more complicated than element-wise addition. In general multiplying a matrix of dimensions `(m x n)` by `(n x p)` would require `m * n * p` multiplications and `m * n * (p - 1)` additions. In the simple "addition" function above, this just requires `m * n` addition operations.